# Zend Framework - many multiple applications 

Tags: zend-framework

I'm starting new project for my company and it's requiring hosting multiple applications under one domain. Each applications must be accessible by different subdomain (wildcards). One of applications will be control panel for all sub-apps. Creating one multi module application is not an option because of complexity of child applications.

All applications must share common libraries and have access to some app specific ones.

I'm still trying to design directory structure that allow store each applications outside public folder, access them dynamically via subdomain and store some files in public folder for each of them separately.

What I've figured out so far :

Host each application with default ZF dir structure in separate dir outside public. Access to public files is possible by plugin printing files to browser from app public directory (witch is outside domains public dir). Only change to default ZF application is thet there is only one index.php file in public_html that starts requested application based on subdomain.

```
domain_dir/
    controllPanel_app/
        application/
            configs/
            modules/
            layouts/
            Bootstrap.php
        library/
        public/
    subApps/
        exampleSub_app/
            application/
            library/
            public/
        anotherExampleSub_app/
            application/
            ...
    common/
        library/
            Zend/
            Other/
    public_html/
        index.php
```

Is this good idea?

Comment: This sounds like a lot of hassle. Can you elaborate on why you think the child applications are too complex for single multi-module application to work? With your solution you're still going to have the same amount of code, but you will have to jump through a lot of hoops to make it work.

Comment: each application will be cms and web service for different complex mobile app. Better explanation is unfortunately beyond my English skills but some of those apps already exists with many modules so mixing it with others is bad idea. Another reason is that chill apps are unrelated to each other and need to work alone.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the way you suggest, but I think it'll be more trouble than it's worth.  Zend Framework is designed for modules if needed, but not sub-apps.  You'll probably end up with a Zend Router nightmare, or some complicated `.htaccess` trickery, both of which would be hard to maintain.

Why not have a totally separate Zend Framework application for each subdomain, and another separate app for your control panel?  Your company (or you yourself) should be able to reconfigure your HTTP server so each subdomain can have its own Document Root.  I do this for my own company, which has a similar situation.  (Common control panel app with different public-facing apps for different purposes, as well as having a common library of shared code.)

You can share a common library folder in multiple ways.  One is if each app adds this folder to its PHP `include_path` in each app's `index.php` or `Bootstrap.php` file.  This is how I prefer to do it.  Another way is through symbolic links within each app's `library` folder.